# In a public-key system using rsa, you intercept the ciphertext c = 15 sent to a user whose public key is e = 5, n = 35. What is the plaintext m?

Tags: rsa

In a public-key system using rsa, you intercept the ciphertext c = 15 sent to a user whose public key is e = 5, n = 35. What is the plaintext m?

In my calculations m=15. But i dont think my calculations are correct

Comment: Good study question. Let's see your calculation steps so that we can help you correct the mistake.

Comment: Also, small modulus such as yours may have some "fixed points", i.e. cipher transcripts that encrypt and decrypt to themselves.

Comment: [5*d][mod(24)]=1. So d=5; based on this , 15^5 mod(35) = 15

Comment: Good, it's correct. This is the exact "fixed point" I was talking about. I confirmed this using Python.

Comment: The next time you have doubt, try some other numbers.